# The usage of "share" confuses me

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

I am reading Harry Potter And The Sorcerer's Stone and there is a paragraph:

> But from that moment on, Hermione Granger became their friend. There are some things you can't share without ending up liking each other, and knocking out a twelve-foot mountain troll is one of them.

The last sentence is hard for me to understand. I thought it should mean `After knocking the troll, they ended up liking each other.`, but I don't understand why it used `share` in that phrase...or I just misunderstood the meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the meaning correct.

The characters experienced the same event together, and therefore ended up liking each other. This is called "sharing" the event, in the same way that you could "share" a pastry with a friend.